# devolver items de un array de objeto javascript

Tags: javascript, array

intento devolver los items disponibles de un objetos de array en caso de no tener devuelve cero, explico un poco el código recorro el objeto con un ciclo y pregunto si el objeto tiene un item y en caso que tenga hago un `push` en una variable stock y el caso que no tenga items devuelvo cero.

```
function checkInventario(inventario, item) {
  inventario = [
     {
      nombre: 'tenedor',
      cantidad: 6
     },
      {
       nombre: 'cuchara',
       cantidad: 4,
    },
   ]
 
  var stock = [];
  for(let i in inventario){
    if(inventario[i].item > 1){
      stock.push(inventario[i].item);
    }else{
      return 0;
    }
    }
    return stock;
  }
```

Comment: El código va como texto por favor

Comment: `inventario.filter(i => i.cantidad> 0)`??

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios errores en tu código

En primer lugar pasas inventario e item como argumentos pero no los usas, ya que inventario lo redeclaras dentro de la función

El parámetro item no se utiliza tampoco.

Si explicas mejor cual es la igualdad que quieres comprobar (Me imagino que cantidad > 0) y para que usas el parámetro item que se pasa a la función (me imagino que para comprobar que ese item existe en el array) te puedo ayudar mejor

Personalmente, también cambiaría para hacer el que el tipo que devuelves siempre sea el mismo. En tu caso, devuelves un array o un 0. Mejor devolver un array vacío así sabes siempre que tipo de objeto esperar en la llamada

En cualquier caso, para que compile lo que has puesto tendría que quedar así

```
function checkInventario(inventario, item) {


 inventario = [
     {
      nombre: 'tenedor',
      cantidad: 6
     },
      {
       nombre: 'cuchara',
       cantidad: 4,
    },
   ]
 
  var stock = [];
  for(let i in inventario){
    if(inventario[i].cantidad > 1){
      stock.push(inventario[i]);
    }else{
      return 0;
    }
    }
    return stock;
  }
```